# Django how to list model objects date wise

Tags: django

I have a model from which I need to list all the objects from a given time period. 
For example: `10-05-2014 to 10-12-2014` 
And then I need to display the objects date wise. Meaning  first display objects created on the `start_date(10-05-2014) up until end_date(10-12-2014)`

```
For example: 
    10-05-2014:
         objects list for that day
    11-05-2014:
         objects list for that day
    and so on until end_date
```

Query:

```
MyModel.objects.unsettled.filter(
            created_on__range=[start_date, end_date]
        )
```

But my problem is how do I list the query set in increasing order by date wise in my template. So that all the objects created on same date will be shown under that date. In short I want to display the list in sections divided by date.

MyModel.objects.unsettled.filter(created_on__range=[start_date, end_date]).order_by("created_on"). But it will just sort the list. How do I group the results.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag:

```
{% for obj in obj_list %}

    {% ifchanged %}
        <h2>{{ obj.created_on|date }}</h2>
    {% endifchanged %}

    <div>{{ obj.name }}</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Another (slightly more complex) option is to use the [`{% regroup %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this. I have to querysets `MyModel.objects.unsettled.filter(created_on=[start_date, end_date])` and   `MyModel.objects.settled.filter(settled_on=[start_date, end_date])`. Now how do I list them date wise.

Comment: I see the two options: 1. group data by date/settled in the view 2. pass single queryset with both settled/unsettled instances ordered by `('created_on', 'settled')` and then use `{% regroup %}` tag twice - for dates first and then for setled flag.

Comment: I understand what you want.  In my opinion if you can pass the list as `MyModel.objects.filter(created_on=[start_date, end_date]).order_by('created_on', 'settled')` then the second option with two `{% regroup %}` tags is a way to go.

Comment: Actually I have two dates `created_on` and `settled_on` with is_settled flag [True/False]. Now on a Particular date some objects can be settled or some objects can be created. Means that date can be `created_on` for some object and `settled_on` for another. So created_on and settled_on should match that particular date. And like wise I need to prepare list of all the objects created or settled over the year date wise

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that there are two different range fields. Then you have to toss the data in the view.  Django template system can't handle this case without support from the python code.